# Finding the expected value of the third suitable cedar cone

Tags: probability

> The cones of the Lebanese cedars have (widest) circumferences that are
>   Gamma-distributed random variables with mean of $5.40\ cm$ and variance
>   of $3.24\ cm^2$. A botanist is interested in collecting cedar cones that have (widest) circumference bigger than $6\ cm$.
>
> How many cones would you
>   expect she will have to inspect in order to find her third target cone?

So I thought I had to use the negative binomial and find its expected value but apparently I don't have the probability of success nor can I find it?

Comment: And we don't really have to look up the mean of the negative binomial, since it is a sum of three independent geometric random variables, and people usually remember the mean of the geometric, "$1/p$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First, we need to find the probability from the gamma distribution.

Given that Variance$(x)=αβ^2$ and Mean$(x)=αβ$, our $α$ and $β$ variables can be found on the intersect of the equations, $5.4=y*x$ and $3.24=y*x^2$.

We find that $α=9$ and $β=.6$. Plugging these values into the gamma distribution, (I used Excel's GAMMA.DIST function):

gammacdf$(6,9,.6)=0.66718...=66.718$%

The $66.718$% is the chance that the tree has a smaller circumference than 6cm, or a failure scenario. We find the success probability through $1-66.718$% or **33.282%**.

### Now we can use the mean of a geometric sequence to find the expected number of trials it will take.

$3/.33282=9.01388$ or, it will take about 9 cones on average to find three that are larger than 6cm in circumference.

.

*Edit:*

*I accidentally used the inverse of the alpha and beta equations the first time, so it is fixed now.*